# All text disappeared (seems to be a database problem)

Tags: database, text

I have an issue with text in my posts. The site is http://2buntu.com.
As I don't own the server, I cannot get direct access to some things. I don't know what caused it but I think it was a plugin I activated. Since then I've tried deactivating plugins, but nothing worked.

I have tracked the source of the problem with the help of a friend, now I need to find a way to fix it (if that is even possible on my end).

> "MYSQL query returned error executing
>   query "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM
>   wp_term_relationships_img AS img WHERE
>   img.object_id = ORDER by
>   term_taxonomy_id" : => You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'ORDER by term_taxonomy_id'
>   at line 1"

That is the error we get. The problem was with an image tagger plugin. I removed the plugin but wordpress is still giving trouble.

I forgot to mention, the posts are not wiped; I can edit them, etc. They just render as blank.

Update:
Site is still not working. I deleted the offending plugin and the table it was using, but it seems post are still not having their content rendered :(. Please! I need help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to retrieve the posts through the Database so you can check the tables, try doing a Google Search for the posts. Type the page URL into the Google Search and look for a cached version. This is definitely not the optimal way to recover the posts, but will work in a worst case scenario.

Comment: the posts are still there, they just render blank.

Comment: Try opening your wp-config.php and changing define('WP_DEBUG', false); TO: define('WP_DEBUG', true); Now you should see any PHP errors.

Comment: How would I access this? I tried to navigate to it, but then realized I can't. The problem is I don't have direct access to the host (I could let him set this up, but so far have not yet).

Answer (score -1):

A friend on AskUbuntu's chat room (Oli) gave me a tip - disable all plugins. I did that and there we are!

Everything is back - except I now I have to reenable a lot of plugins :/...

If found the **real** culprit too. The facebook like button plugin I had enabled. I deleted it now (wasn't working well anyway).